# Change mobile provision of IPA file

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, mobile, ipa

I have an `IPA` file generated with `XCode` with 3 devices embedded in his mobile provision file. I've added 2 additional devices on the mobile provision on apple developer web. Is there any way to install the `IPA` file on these new devices without regenerating the `IPA` file on `XCode`?(or at least, without using a Mac).

The devices has `iOS 9.2`. It seems with `iOS 7` the mobile provision file  installs easily, but with 9.2 devices it can't be possible to install the mobile provision file, even with diawi service.

I'm using Standard program Ad-hoc distribution. With this program i can distribute until 100 devices.

Comment: there is no way. You have to regenerate and build new IPA again.

Comment: try the Test Flight app feature provided by iTunes Connect. There you can create internal testers and send installation link via email.

Answer (score 2):

There is no possibility to run the app without add the devices to your developer account. You need to add first and then generate another IPA . This is the possibility by my experience. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One standard way could be you can upload your IPA file to iTunes connect and Test it using Test flight app (Create internal user for that) the will receive email through which the can install IPA and you will not required to add new device id's hope this will help.